# How can I send image (<img/>) via form's submit to my java servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, php, jquery, html

I'm using croppie framework to generate new picture on my website. After that, I want to pass this new image to my java servlet. The best way to do it  would be via form, but json also would be good. 
Unfortunately, I don't know how can i do this.

This is a part of code which creates new image:

```js
function popupResult(result) {
  var html;
  if (result.html) {
    html = result.html;
  }
  if (result.src) {
    html = '<img  id="blah" src="' + result.src + '" width="170" height="200" />';
  }

  $('.profilowe').html(html);
}

function cropping() {
  var $uploadCrop;
  function readFile(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $uploadCrop.croppie('bind', {
          url: e.target.result
        });
        $('.showPicture').addClass('ready');
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
    else {
      swal("Sorry - you're browser doesn't support the FileReader API");
    }
  }

  $uploadCrop = $('#showPicture').croppie({
    viewport: {
      width: 170,
      height: 220,
      type: 'square'
    },
    boundary: {
      width: 300,
      height: 300
    },
    exif: true
  });

  $('#upload').on('change', function () { if(ValidateSingleInput(this)){readFile(this); }});
  $('.upload-result').on('click', function (ev) {
    $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
      type: 'canvas',
      size: 'viewport'
    }).then(function (resp) {
      popupResult({
        src: resp
      });
    });
  });
}
```

and the html element:(First is using to generate new image, second is replaced by new image)

```
<input type='file' id="upload"/>
<div class="profilowe">
   <img id="blah" src="blank.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: `reader.readAsDataURL` gives you a data-url you could send, no?

Comment: encode you image to base64 encoding and then submit that string